Application of the Duality Principle in Boolean Algebra
Can the Duality Principle in Boolean Algebra be applied to prove theorems in different branches of Mathematics? I ask because of the following: First, let multiplication signify conjunction, so that AB signifies A and B. Second, let addition signify disjunction, so that A+B signifies A or B. Third, let equality signify the biconditional, so that A=B signifies A iff B. Fourth, let F signify False. Fifth, let T signify True. Now consider the following:
1.A=X is prime
2.¬A=X isn’t prime
3.B=X is odd
4.¬B=X isn’t odd
5.∀X(A→B)=F
6.Use the duality principle on (5)
7.∃X((¬A)B)=T
However, on the contrary the following could be leveled against using the duality principle.
1.C=X is a cat
2.¬C=X isn’t a cat
3.D=X is a mammal
4.¬D=X isn’t a mammal
5.∀X(C→D)=T
6.Use the duality principle on (5)
7.∃X((¬C)D)=F
8.However (7) seems false since there does exist something that isn’t a cat which is also a mammal.
9.However, does this criticism taken from real life also apply to mathematics as well

The negation of $p\to q$ is $p\land \lnot q$, not $\lnot p\land q$.
So your line (7) should read $\exists X\, (C(\lnot D))=F$.
Indeed, it is fase that there exists something which is a cat and not a mammal.
